# How to compute rolling window, then groupby, followed by aggregation without looping?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rolling-computation

I have a pandas dataframe `updates` as follows:

```
                        streamid,low,high
time
2023-01-10 16:07:36.264,979,1.07331,1.07344
2023-01-10 16:07:36.359,1009,1.07331,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.444,781,1.07329,1.07341
2023-01-10 16:07:36.464,979,1.07331,1.07344
2023-01-10 16:07:36.470,1191,1.07331,1.0734
2023-01-10 16:07:36.480,1191,1.07333,1.07342
2023-01-10 16:07:36.493,2,1.07332,1.07337
2023-01-10 16:07:36.493,1009,1.07332,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.494,979,1.07332,1.07345
2023-01-10 16:07:36.494,786,1.07325,1.07332
2023-01-10 16:07:36.494,141,1.07332,1.07337
2023-01-10 16:07:36.496,1263,1.07332,1.07339
2023-01-10 16:07:36.496,818,1.07331,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.497,786,1.07325,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.499,844,1.07331,1.07336
2023-01-10 16:07:36.499,1009,1.07332,1.07339
2023-01-10 16:07:36.501,1028,1.07333,1.07337
2023-01-10 16:07:36.503,141,1.07333,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.504,1009,1.07333,1.0734
2023-01-10 16:07:36.509,1009,1.07333,1.07341
2023-01-10 16:07:36.509,786,1.07327,1.07335
```

I want to compute a rolling max of `low` and a rolling min of `high` in a `5s` window with a caveat: if in any window, there are multiple rows with the same `streamid`, only the latest row should be considered.

Conceptually, this should be easy: All I need do is to get rolling windows of `5s` each, perform a `groupby` on streamid, call `last()` on the GroupBy object to get the correct row for each group, and then do `agg({"low": "max", "high": "min"})` on the rolling window.

In practice, I found out that I cannot do `groupby` on a rolling window since rolling is applied on each column separately. I understand that I can use `method='table'` in `rolling`, and `engine='numba', raw=True` in `apply` to get entire dataframes in my custom function, but I am not able to do groupby inside the numba function.

Here is my looping solution that is insanely slow, but gives the right answer:

```
from itertools import islice
lows = []
highs = []
times = []
rolled = past_updates.rolling("5s")
for index, df in enumerate(islice(rolled, None)):
    low, high = df.groupby(["streamid"]).last().agg({"low": "max", "high": "min"})
    lows.append(low)
    highs.append(high)
    times.append(df.index[-1])
out_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "low": lows, "high": highs, "time": times
}).set_index("time")
```

This gives the result:

```
                        low,high
time
2023-01-10 16:07:36.264,1.07331,1.07344
2023-01-10 16:07:36.359,1.07331,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.444,1.07331,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.464,1.07331,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.470,1.07331,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.480,1.07333,1.07338
2023-01-10 16:07:36.493,1.07333,1.07337
2023-01-10 16:07:36.493,1.07333,1.07337
2023-01-10 16:07:36.494,1.07333,1.07337
2023-01-10 16:07:36.494,1.07333,1.07332
2023-01-10 16:07:36.494,1.07333,1.07332
2023-01-10 16:07:36.496,1.07333,1.07332
2023-01-10 16:07:36.496,1.07333,1.07332
2023-01-10 16:07:36.497,1.07333,1.07333  # <-- 1.07332 is dropped due to new update from 786
2023-01-10 16:07:36.499,1.07333,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.499,1.07333,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.501,1.07333,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.503,1.07333,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.504,1.07333,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.509,1.07333,1.07333
2023-01-10 16:07:36.509,1.07333,1.07335
```

Unfortunately, this takes 7-8 minutes for ~600k rows. I want to be able to do this many times for different timestamps. Is there a better way, potentially one that avoids loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of iteration, I got this to work utilizing numba engine. Here is my implementation for anyone in a similar situation:

```
def group_and_agg(subarray):
    streamupdate_l = {}
    streamupdate_h = {}
    for row in subarray:
        if ~np.isnan(row[1]):
            streamupdate_l[row[0]] = row[1]
        if ~np.isnan(row[2]):
            streamupdate_h[row[0]] = row[2]
     
    lowmax = max(streamupdate_l.values())
    highmin = min(streamupdate_h.values())
    return highmin - lowmax, lowmax, highmin

condensed = past_updates.rolling("5s", method="table").apply(group_and_agg,
                                                 engine="numba",
                                                 raw=True)
```

While it still uses loops, it is much faster!
For the same input of 600k rows, this takes `15s` to run. One issue is that for some reason, the output needs to be of the same shape as the input, so I have to return one additional quantity even though I don't need it (`highmin-lowmax` in my case). Furthermore the returned dataframe `condensed` has the same column names as `past_updates`, so it needs to be renamed for clarity. Happily, the index names are correctly inferred from the rolling windows.

Answer (score 0):

The caveat is tricky. Do you want to keep duplicate streamids in general? If not drop duplicates on streamid

```
df.drop_duplicates(on='streamid',keep='last',inplace=True)
```

Reassign the lows and highs

```
df.low = df.low.rolling(window="5s").max()
df.high = df.high.rolling(window="5s").min()
```

If you need to keep duplicates I don't know if there's a workaround that wouldn't involve a for loop.

Comment: Dropping duplicates from the get go is a problem because it would only keep one update in the entire df. I want one update in each rolling window.